# How to read aps payload on app launch when app was not in running state

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

How can I read the aps payload upon receiving push notification and the app is being launched from not running state. 
Here is what I tried.
In side app delegate class , in side the function

```
FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    if (options != null){
     if (options.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey)){
       NSDictionary userInfo =(NSDictionary)options[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
       if (userInfo != null){
         if (null != options && options.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
                {
                    NSDictionary aps = options.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;
           if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("title")))
                        title = (aps[new NSString("title")] as NSString).ToString();
                 }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not able to read the data. But if the app is in running state(active/inactive) I am able to read in this way from the method

```
ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the correct way. options doesnt that have the data directly, instead had to check in userinfo which is inside options

```
FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    if (options != null){
     if (options.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey)){
       NSDictionary userInfo =(NSDictionary)options[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
       if (userInfo != null){
         if (null != userInfo && userInfo .ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
                {
                    NSDictionary aps = userInfo .ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;
           if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("title")))
                        title = (aps[new NSString("title")] as NSString).ToString();
                 }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's with userInfo != null then another null != userInfo ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

```
//---------------------------------------------------
    //Handel Push notification
    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        // Here app will open from pushnotification
        //RemoteNotification
        NSDictionary* dictionary1 = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        //LocalNotification
        NSDictionary* dictionary2 = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
        if (dictionary1 != nil)
        {
            //RemoteNotification Payload
            NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary1);
            // here set you code
        }
        if (dictionary2 != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Launched from dictionary2dictionary2dictionary2 notification: %@", dictionary2);
            double delayInSeconds = 7;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                // [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:dictionary2 updateUI:NO];
            });
        }

     }
     else
         {}
```

Comment: I am able to detect whether the launch happened from push or not form the LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey . But unable to read any data from the apns payload

Comment: Can you paste your apns payload here?